# Property Change Event for C# ..Parent child interaction

Tags: c#, event-handling, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class Step that stores a list of Tasks :

```
public class Step
    {

        public string StepName { get; set; }

        private string _stepStatus 

        public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public string StepStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _stepStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _stepStatus = value;
        }  
   }

        public Step(String name)
        {
            StepName = name;

            Tasks = new List<Task>();

        }
```

I have a class of Task :

```
  public class Task
    {

    public string TaskName { get; set; }

    private string _taskStatus 
    public string TaskStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _taskStatus;
        }
        set
        {
           // raise an event here
            _taskStatus = value;
        }  
   }
    public Task(String name)
    {
        TaskName = name;

    }
```

Whenever an individual updates a Task , I want to raise an event . this event should be caught by the parent i.e Step .. Step should check the status of all the tasks .

If all tasks' status are  New , then Step status should be automatically set to New . 
If all tasks' status are Finished , then Step status should be automatically set to Finished.
If even on of the task's status is  In Progress , the Step Status should be set to In Progress.
 I shall call this method TripleLogic , say.

I can do the logic for the above three since this is logical. I am not sure how to raise an event from Task Status setter and ensure that Step class object picks it up since I am new to C#. If someone could help me with this event raising part with a small sample code , and also show me how I cna get my parent Step object to capture this event and call TripleLogic at that instance.

I looked at INotifyPropertyChanged but am not sure how to implement.
Any other code design related pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Try starting here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: You could make `StepStatus` a read only property. Within the `get` of `StepStatus` you check your child list for the child status by the given logic and return your StepStatus string. If you need events you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or raise a custom event for the childs and you need `ListChangedEvent` to manage new added Tasks to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggestion is not not expose your `Tasks` property on the `Step` class so that consumers are not able to modify the collection whenever/however they want. Instead add a method called `AddTask(Task t)` to `Step` and in there you can set up your event handling.

The `Task` class should expose an event, perhaps called `StatusChanged`. When the setter on the `TaskStatus` property is called, fire that event (after checking to ensure there are listeners). This event's arguments should include the updated status and the task's name. If you have a finite set of statuses, I'd suggest defining an enum for them, instead of relying on strings.

Example:

```
public class Task
{
    public event EventHandler<TaskStatusEventArgs> StatusChanged;
    //...
}

public enum TaskStatus
{
    New,

    InProgress,

    Done
}

public class TaskStatusEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public string TaskName { get; private set; }

    public TaskStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public TaskStatusEventArgs(string taskName, TaskStatus status)
    {
        TaskName = taskName;
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Back in `Step` and the `AddTask()` method, subscribe to the `Task`'s `StatusChanged` event and keep track of the number of tasks in the `Step`. In the handler for the `StatusChanged` event, you can then grab the task's new status and do whatever logic you need in your `TripleLogic()` method.

Example:

```
public class Step
{
    List<Task> tasks;

    public void AddTask(Task t)
    {
        t.StatusChanged += HandleStatusChanged;
    }

    private void HandleStatusChanged(object sender, TaskStatusEventArgs args)
    {
        string taskName = args.TaskName;
        TaskStatus status = args.Status;

        TripleLogic(taskName, status);
    }
}
```

Given that you've mentioned you are new to C#, perhaps go through the MSDN [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) for events, specifically the sections on [subscribing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) and [publishing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx). The publishing section mentions the generic `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` delegate, I highly suggest using that method.

Your question is vague and large-enough that, when coupled with your lack of experience in the language, this may take you a while to get through.

Comment: Thank you. your suggestions are very useful . I am forced to make the List<Task> public because I have to XMLSerialize them . I thought it won't be relevant and hence simplified my code sample here but turns out it unfortunaley is . Before I upvote your answer ,I'd just like to know if i can add the Status Change listener with my original public List<Task> instead of the Add task method ? may be thru a getter or setter of the List<Task>

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan if in the setter the collection is fully populated (as I imagine would be the case in your serialization scenario), then yes, you could loop through the items in the setter and add a listener for each item in the collection.

Comment: And for the sake of completeness, perhaps unsubscribe from any existing tasks in that same setter before adding the listeners for the new ones.

Comment: here is the catch in this this method .when i make a new step and add the subsequent tasks to it , i am attaching the handler t.StatusChanged += HandleStatusChanged;  when i open an exisitng step in my app , xml deserialization takes care of making the step and populating the tasks. thus , xml serialization does not use the Add method when u open an already created step and task. as a  result , the change handler does not get added when i open a step second time.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan Right, that's why I said you'd need to attach the handler in the setter as well

Comment: u mean the setter of the List or the setter of the status ?

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan setter of the list

Comment: thats what doesnt work. The deserializer doesnt seem to go through the setter of the list . it rather seems to create the list and add entries to it. but then again it wont use my custom AddTask method to add.. it uses the inbuilt add for List<>